# How to add smtp hotmail account to send mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I wrote some codes so as to send e mail but I can only send mail from gmail account to gmail account  also, I want to use hotmail accounts how can i do it? thanks 
It is

```
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
mail.From = new MailAddress("xxx@gmail.com");
mail.To.Add("kalaylevent@gmail.com");
mail.Subject = "Test Mail - 1";
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
string htmlBody;
htmlBody = "Write some HTML code here";
mail.Body = htmlBody;
SmtpServer.Port = 587;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("kalaylevent@gmail.com", "mypassword");
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Comment: you just place the email to: To.Add(themail@hotmail)

Comment: I cannot send mail to hotmail account by using this method I guess that I have to add general smpt server bla....

Comment: You have an hotmail account and do you want to send mail to someone using their Smtp Service or do you want send mail to an hotmail account using gmail Smtp Service?

Comment: Yes, I want to send mail to hotmail account or from hotmail account so, I want to use hotmail and gmail together

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I changed a little of code and it tested successfully (from Hotmail to Gmail)

```
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");
var mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("youremail@hotmail.com");
mail.To.Add("to@gmail.com");
mail.Subject = "Test Mail - 1";
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
string htmlBody;
htmlBody = "Write some HTML code here";
mail.Body = htmlBody;
SmtpServer.Port = 587;
SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("youremail@hotmail.com", "password");
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Thanks, it is so helpful for me

Comment: Also, how can i check the smtp authentication so, Firstly it check the authetication if it is true , the user can send mail after authentication response(it is mail password or username true or not)

Comment: sorry,this question i can't answer you because i also don't know.but i can give you some suggest,you can use tcp/ip with smtp protocol and connect the smtp server.this open mail server may be can help you .[LumiSoft Mail Server](http://www.lumisoft.ee/lsWWW/ENG/Products/Mail_Server/mail_index_eng.aspx?type=info),the simple method is use try..exception.if get authentication failed then you can use other account.

Comment: thanks +1, it takes some time for the mail to send, can i make it instant?

Comment: Why did you call smtpSERVER a variable of type SmtpCLIENT?

Comment: PLEASE NOTE

Hotmail, Outlook.com SMTP Server
Hotmail/Live/Outlook.com SMTP server address is 

smtp.office365.com 

(smtp.live.com does not work anymore)

Answer (score 4):

I use different smtp client and make sure to set the socket options to **StartTls** :

```
 using (SmtpClient client = new())
  {
     try 
     {
           await client.ConnectAsync("smtp.office365.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
                        client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
                        
           await client.AuthenticateAsync("Your_User_Name", "Your_Password");

           await client.SendAsync(mailMessage);
        }
        catch
        {
           //log an error message or throw an exception, or both.
           throw;
       }
       finally
       {
            await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
            client.Dispose();
       }
 }
```

Comment: Wich nuget package is this using?

Comment: @PerG, Here is the nuget package that I'm using: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NETCore.MailKit/