# exception while sending mail multiple recipient

Tags: c#, system.net.mail

I am trying to send an email to Multiple email addresses. But I am getting this exception

```
A recipient must be specified
```

at this line

`smtp.Send(mail);`

I have checked related posts on stackoverflow then
 I have tried to add this line

```
 mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(c[0].Address));
```

but this time exception message says

`: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.3 Requested action aborted; user not authenticated`

**This is my code:**

```
  MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

            mail.From = new MailAddress(emailFrom);

            MailAddressCollection c = new MailAddressCollection();


            c.Add(new MailAddress("sendto@gmail.com"));

            mail.Subject = "some word";
            mail.Body = "some word";
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;


            if (c[0].Address.Contains("yahoo"))
            {

                using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient())
                {

                    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailFrom,PASS);


                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtp.Send(mail);
                }
            }
            else if (c[0].Address.Contains("hotmail"))
            {

                using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    smtp.Port = 587;
                    smtp.Host = "smtp.live.com";
                    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailFrom, PASS);


                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtp.Send(mail);
                }
            }

            else if (c[0].Address.Contains("gmail"))
            {

                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;

                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailFrom,PASS)


                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(mail);
            }
```

Comment: I assume your `emailFrom` has your local network domain's credential, and it has some restrictions to sending mails. If that is the case you might want to get it sorted out from Network admin

Comment: These are 2 separate issues. The first is that an email needs at least one recipient. You fixed this correctly with `mail.To.Add()`. Your issue now is that `smtp.live.com` is rejecting the credentials you are sending it. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9851590/1901857) may help

Comment: I dont understand .I have been working on for hours .I am using gmail account and this code works if i send an email to a gmail account something wrong with hotmail settings.I cant figure out .credentials are correct I have checked while debugging